# how to format a diff/patch file to apply it with cweagans/composer-patches

Tags: composer-php, diff, patch

i wanted to utilize cweagans/composer-patches to apply patches to 3rd party packages.

So i fixed a bug and exported the patch using diff

```sh
cd path/to/package
diff -u fileA fileB > /path/to/project/patch.diff
```

and added to composer.json:

```
{
    "patches": {
        "vendor/packagekey": {
            "Bug description": "patch.diff"
        }
    }
}
```

When executing composer install i get

`Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch`

Do i HAVE TO install the package from source and format the patch using git diff?

If i need to install the package from source - how do i tell composer to only install that package from source? I dont want to install all packages from source...

update:
thats what the patchfile looks like

```
--- Resources/Private/Templates/ImageManipulation/ImageManipulationElement.html 2020-08-12 13:37:40.759056419 +0200
+++ Resources/Private/Templates/ImageManipulation/ImageManipulationElement.html2    2020-08-12 13:37:28.694963559 +0200
@@ -19,7 +19,7 @@
                                    data-severity="notice"
                                    data-modal-title="{f:render(partial: 'ModalTitle', section:'Main', arguments: _all)}"
                                    data-image-uid="{image.uid}"
-                                   data-crop-variants="{config.cropVariants -> f:format.json()}'"
+                                   data-crop-variants='{config.cropVariants -> f:format.json()}'
                                    data-button-preview-text="{f:translate(key:'LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_wizards.xlf:imwizard.preview')}"
                                    data-button-dismiss-text="{f:translate(key:'LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_wizards.xlf:imwizard.cancel')}"
                                    data-button-save-text="{f:translate(key:'LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_wizards.xlf:imwizard.accept')}"
```

Comment: Have you checked the patch? Maybe you've built it the wrong way (showing the diff between your version and the original code, such that your changes are denoted as "removed lines" and the original parts as "added code")

Comment: @NicoHaase i added the patch file.

Comment: What do you mean by "I dont want to install all packages from source"? Most PHP packages are installed by their sources, only some provide a PHAR, but AFAIK that is not used when installing with Composer

Comment: No, its about NOT loading the vcs files if possible

Comment: What do you mean by "NOT loading the vcs files"? Can you clarify that, and edit that into your question?

Comment: i mean the whole vcs (git for example) repository, that i dont really need for third-party packages. Why do i have to put that in the original quesion? Thats basic composer usage (--prefer-source / --prefere-dist)

Comment: Both ways of installing provide the same result, and AFAIK that plugin runs on the final file system, so that should not make a difference. But as I am reviewing the patch file: have you thought about reporting that as a bug, or forking the original repository? Maybe you could avoid patching completely this way?

Comment: Yes, i did and it turned out i sabotaged my own stack: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/91987#change-429005 Still if you report a bug like this (if its a valid bug) you need a patch because in oss it can take a while until an issue gets a patchlevel-release ;) This question remains valid though

Comment: Which **exact** question is open? How to format that diff? You've answered that this works. Whether the "vcs files are needed? Well, which other format are you looking for? Have you tried using a dist package, and this does not work? According to the answer: "If you already installed the dist-package,..." - Composer does not re-require a package this way, maybe you should try to remove the files from `vendor` and run `composer install`?

Answer (score -2):

By installing the package from source and calling `git diff > /path/to/project/patch.diff` it works.

But the original question remains valid - can i use a regular diff file with composer-patches?

Install a package from source:

```sh
composer require --prefer-source vendor/package
```

If you already installed the dist-package, simply run the command again with the --prefer-source parameter.

Comment: Please edit the main question to contain all information. Don't use the answer section to clarify your question

Comment: The question is how to format a patch using diff, this is a way to do it using git diff, which is some kind of answer, but not the accepted answer. So whats the deal with having this as a possible solution if someone stumbles across this issue because he/she experiences the same?